# how to have an email communication system like elance within a php (or cakephp) application

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I want to build an application which allows my users to communicate directly with each other via email, just like the way elance does, but I can't figure out how I'd go about it.

On elance if someone messages you through the site you get an email from elance which you can reply to and it will email the person who sent you the message. All this goes through elance, which is to say the email you get and reply to is an address like

```
E63213456-WR@workroom.elance.com
```

And if you reply to that address then it knows somehow who to forward the email on to. So the person who  originally sent the email gets a response from a similar elance email address and the two users never see each others actual real email addresses.

Can anyone give me some pointers. Is it possible to set up a function which receives these emails and deals with them? If so how?

I'm using cakephp 2 so if there's a cakey way to do this that would be handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone give me some pointers. Is it possible to set up a function which receives these emails and deals with them? If so how?

Well, I'm clearly not going to write the code for you but here's the concept:

- [Connect to the mail server](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20get%20email%20from%20server)
- Pull a list of emails
- Parse the subject string for whatever identifier you need (guess its E63213456 in your example)
- Do something with the identifier
- Optionally parse the body for something you need from it and do something with it

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to craete dynamic mail box (first) like 12345@workroom.elance.com, 6789@workroom.example.com, 58479@workroom.example.com
here these 12345, 6789 etc are the unique code for each communication

then you need to fetch that mail from mail server from your DB for that  you can use php built in function [imap_createmailbox](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-createmailbox.php)

Or you can also take helps from 
https://github.com/escobar022/php-imap-ToDB